# Converting Excel computation to code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a large Excel spreadsheet with lots of formulas in it.  Some data is typed in by the user, and lots of cells are calculated.

Need to convert this Excel-based job to actual code. Is where any way to pull all the formulas out the Excel into a file, a coding project, etc.?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I've removed your `visual-studio` tag as this question doesn't pertain to the Visual Studio IDE itself. I've likewise done the same for the `eclipse` tag. You can see their tag wikis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/info) respectively.

Comment: As a suggestion to help you find an answer to your question: I doubt there is a tool to do this because it's not really a common thing to do and the code and such tool would likely generate very strange code. It's better to write the code from scratch.

Comment: You can always zip the excel file, then examine the XML of the sheet of interest. Everything should be documented there. Formulas are surrounded with the `<f>` tag, while formula values are in `<v>` tag. You could parse this as well, to get at what you need.

Comment: Loop through cells, storing the `Range([whatever cell]).formula`?

Comment: @john i don't expect to use that code directly, just need to understand what the spreadsheet does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick script that will output formulas in the activesheet with their corresponding cell address

```
Sub ExportFormulas()

    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\formulas.txt"

    Open myFile For Output As #1

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If InStr(cel.Formula, "=") > 0 Then
            Write #1, cel.Address, cel.Formula
        End If
    Next cel

    Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. Where would I put that script? 
I am a newbie as far as working with Excel.